# Intuition behind holomorphic convexity

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

We define the holomorphically convex hull of a set $M \subset D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ to be the set $$\widehat{M} : = \{ z \in D : \left| f(z) \right| \leq \| f \|_M \ \forall f \in \mathscr{O}(D) \},$$ where $\| f \|_M : = \sup_{z \in K} \left| f(z)\right|$, for all compact sets $K \subset D$ and $\mathscr{O}(D)$ denotes the space of holomorphic functions on the domain $D$.

I have absolutely no intuition for what this definition means.

I am comfortable with the notion of a convex hull, but not sure how this is a generalisation of that, if it is.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the standard convex hull that you are familiar with. The convex hull of a set $K$ is the smallest convex set that contains $K$. We may rephrase this to mean the intersection of all half spaces that contain $K$ or even better, we may define this to be the set of all points such that all $(\mathbb{C}$-)linear maps $\ell$ which take values not exceeding their maximum on $K$. Formally, we may then write the convex hull as $$\text{conv}(K) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n : \left| \ell(z) \right| \leq \| \ell \|_K\},$$ for all complex linear functionals on $K$.

Replacing $\ell$ by holomorphic functions, we obtain the definition for a holomorphically convex hull.

Exercise: Prove that the holomorphically convex hull is contained in the (linear-)convex hull.

Comment: This is a very useful answer. I think in your formula for the convex hull of a set $K$ you assumed implicitly that $K$ is closed. Of course this is certainly true for the case of compact $K$, which OP asked about.

Comment: @Blazej I appreciate your comment. I have written up some detailed notes on the different notions of convexity, i.e., extending the above answer. Would you like me to send them to you?

Comment: @AmorFati: Hi and apologies for replying to your answer out of the blue after such a long time! If I understand correctly, your formal definition of the *complex* convex hull (i.e. using complex-linear functionals) does *not* produce the usual convex hull (defined by real-linear functions), correct? That is, is it a **strictly formal** definition, or can one actually show that both notions in fact coincide under reasonable topological assumptions on $K$?